# SQL Update - Updating selected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have a table named `MYTABLE` with two columns: `ID`, `STATUS`

I want to write a stored procedure that returns the records whose `STATUS` is 0. But this stored proc must update the `STATUS` of returned rows to 1. How can I do this selecting and updating operation in a single query?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
update MyTable
set Status = 1
output inserted.*
where Status = 0
```

If you want to return what the table looked like before the update you should use deleted.* instead.

```
update MyTable
set Status = 1
output deleted.*
where Status = 0
```

You can of course use both if you like and you don't have to use `*`. You can specify the columns you are interested in.

```
update MyTable
set Status = 1
output inserted.ID, inserted.status, deleted.status as OldStatus
where Status = 0
```

Comment: Damn forgot about output - i blame being forced to use sql2000 too often!

Comment: @CResults – So true. I should mention that this works from SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Can probably be done using the [`OUTPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.