# Sql Server select and update X rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, row-number

I'm using Sql Server 2012.

I need to select rows from a table for processing.  The number of rows needs to be variable.  I need to update the rows I'm selecting to a "being processed" status - I have a guid to populate for this purpose.

I've encountered several examples of using row_number() and a couple of examples of ways of using CTE's, but I'm not sure on how to combine them (or if that's even the correct strategy).  I would appreciate any insight.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @SessionGuid uniqueidentifier,  @rowcount bigint
SELECT @rowcount = 1000
SELECT @sessionguid = newid()

    DECLARE @myProductChanges table (
            ProductChangeId bigint
        ,   ProductTypeId smallint
        ,   SourceSystemId tinyint
        ,   ChangeTypeId tinyint );

    WITH NextPage AS 
    (
       SELECT 
           ProductChangeId, ServiceSessionGuid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductChangeId) AS 'RowNum' 
       FROM dbo.ProductChange
       WHERE 'RowNum' < @rowcount
    )
    UPDATE dbo.ProductChange
    SET ServiceSessionGuid = @sessionguid, ProcessingStateId = 2, UpdatedDate = getdate()
    OUTPUT
        INSERTED.ProductChangeId,
        INSERTED.ProductTypeId,
        INSERTED.SourceSystemId,
        INSERTED.ChangeTypeId
    INTO @myProductChanges
    FROM dbo.ProductChange as pc join NextPage on pc.ProductChangeId = NextPage.ProductChangeId
```

From here I will select from my temp table and return the data:

```
SELECT mpc.ProductChangeId
    ,   pt.ProductName as ProductType
    ,   ss.Name as SourceSystem
    ,   ct.ChangeDescription as ChangeType
FROM @myProductChanges as mpc 
        join dbo.R_ProductType pt on mpc.ProductTypeId = pt.ProductTypeId
        join dbo.R_SourceSystem ss on mpc.SourceSystemId = ss.SourceSystemId
        join dbo.R_ChangeType ct on mpc.ChangeTypeId = ct.ChangeTypeId
ORDER BY ProductType asc
```

So far this doesn't work for me.  I get an error when I try to run it:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 20
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

I'm not clear on what I'm doing wrong - so - any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

BTW, here are some of the questions I've used as reference to try and solve this:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777178](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777178/sql-server-how-to-select-a-fixed-amount-of-rows-select-every-x-th-value)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319842](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319842/select-rows-and-update-same-rows-for-locking)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402103/sql-update-updating-selected-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This subquery makes no sense:

```
   SELECT 
       ProductChangeId, ServiceSessionGuid,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductChangeId) AS 'RowNum' 
   FROM dbo.ProductChange
   WHERE 'RowNum' < @rowcount
```

You can't reference the alias `RowNum` at the same scope (and you are trying to compare a string, not an alias, anyway), because when the `WHERE` clause is parsed, the `SELECT` list hasn't been materialized yet. What you need is either another nest:

```
SELECT ProductChangeId, ServiceSessionGuid, RowNum
FROM (SELECT ProductChangeId, ServiceSessionGuid, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductChangeId) AS RowNum
   FROM dbo.ProductChange
) AS x WHERE RowNum < @rowcount
```

Or:

```
SELECT TOP (@rowcount-1) ProductChangeId, ServiceSessionGuid, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductChangeId) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.ProductChange
ORDER BY ProductChangeId
```

Also please stop using `'alias'` - when you need to delimit aliases (you don't in this case), use `[square brackets]`.

Comment: So my error is related to the comparison of 'RowNum' (as a string value and not an alias) to @rowcount - that explains a lot.  I borrowed from an example I found in an attempt to make this work.

Comment: In the second example (SELECT TOP...), do I still need ROW_NUMBER() in order to make sure that I get the next 'N' rows ordered by ProductChangeId column?

Comment: No, TOP will limit to that number of rows, but I wasn't sure if you needed the row_number() for other reasons...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but I think you want `<=` rather than `<` if you want to affect `@rowcount` rows, not one less.

Another tip is that CTEs can be updated directly*, as shown here:

```
WITH NextPage AS 
(
   SELECT TOP(@rowcount) *           
   FROM dbo.ProductChange
)
UPDATE NextPage
SET ServiceSessionGuid = @sessionguid, ProcessingStateId = 2, UpdatedDate = getdate()
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.ProductChangeId,
    INSERTED.ProductTypeId,
    INSERTED.SourceSystemId,
    INSERTED.ChangeTypeId
INTO @myProductChanges
```

** The updates affect the base table in the CTE, i.e. dbo.ProductChange*

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I do want to make my code (even SQL) as succinct and efficient as I can.

And yes, I did actually want <=, point taken.